# Google Apps API Explorer: BadRequest Error with directory.groups.list

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-api-client, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I have setup my google developers account.
Enabled Admin API and also gave credentials with localhost as Authorized origin.

I am trying to explore the Directory API to fetch the list of groups. But it always throws 400 BadRequest error.

Also, I have tried with JavaScript as follows.

```
gapi.auth.authorize with the CLIENT_ID and scopes as admin.directory.group, admin.directory.group.readonly

gapi.client.load('admin', 'directory_v1', function(){
   var request = gapi.client.directory.groups.list();
   request.execute(function(resp) {
          // usage of resp object
   });
});
```

This also gives me the same error. [resp object returns BadRequest error object].

I am using the correct CLIENT_ID and also gave Authorized origins. What am I doing wrong or missing in this?

~Madhu

Answer (score 0):

Are you authenticating as a super admin user or a delegated admin user who has permissions to read groups?